# IE: XMLSerializer serializes "xml:lang" attribute with adding "xmlns:xml" attribute

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xml-parsing, microsoft-edge, browser-extension

I'm writing a browser extension, which serializes document to XML and sends it to backend (which is blackboxed for us).

When serializer meets "xml:lang" attribute on tag, it adds (only in IE, Edge) "xmlns:xml" namespace definition to that node.

Which results in XML parsing error on the backend.

How can I serialize without adding "xmlns:xml" attributes?

```js
// We create DOM node by parsing it from string
// Then we serialize it again
var content = "'<span id="el" xml:lang="ar" lang="ar">سالم</span>'";
var el = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, 'application/xml');

var serialized = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(el);
console.log(serialized);

// <span id="el" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">سالم</span>
// Serializing parsed node: attribute 'xmlns:xml' is added, how do I get rid of that?
```

Answer (score -1):

I've recently run into the same problem. I don't know of any way to prevent it, but doing a string replace to strip it out should be pretty reliable:

```
var cleanedXmlStr = xmlStr.replace(
    /\sxmlns\:xml=['"]http\:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/XML\/1998\/namespace['"]/g, '');
```

Another option would be to use a third-party serializer like this one:

https://github.com/cburgmer/xmlserializer